# Castear clase con distinto numero de atributos en typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, class, casting

Tengo 2 clases en angular de las cuales una hereda de la otra. Al querer igualar un objeto de la clase hija con uno de la clase padre, la cual ya se encuentra con los atributos definidos, obtengo un error en el que me dice que no puedo igualar los objetos puesto que se pierden los atributos de la clase hija. Como puedo hacer para igualar los objetos y después definir los atributos restantes?

Estos son los atributos de la clase padre

```
export class BlockParamModel{    
pregAbiertas : OpenQuestionParamsModel[];
    idExamenContenedor : number;
    titulo: string;
    valor: number;
    descripcion: string;
    tieneAdjuntos: number;
    idExamen: number;
    idCurso: number;
    posicion: number;
    visible: number;
```

y estos es la clase hija

```
export class BlockModel extends BlockParamModel{
    id:number;
    next:boolean = false;
    prev:boolean = false;
    editing:boolean = false;
    answerDescription = false;
    answers : OpenQuestionExamModel[] = [];
```

estoy intentando hacer esto.

```
let blockParam : BlockParamModel;
    let block:BlockModel = blockParam;
```

pero obtengo el siguiente mensaje: Type 'BlockParamModel' is missing the following properties from type 'BlockModel': id, next, prev, editing, and 2 more.

Comment: Muéstranos el código de tus clases y lo que intentas hacer. Así será más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Estas tratando de pasar el padre a la hija. querrias hacer al reves?

Comment: Muestra mas codigo por favor. Con el poco código que muestras solo puedo ver que te faltarian los new de las clases.

Comment: Con la informacion que tienes es insuficiente. Puedes explicar cual es el resultado final que deseas? Da la impresion que lo estas haciendo al reves. Recuerda seguir las premisas de SOLID cuando estes creando clases e interfaces.